# I18n for model-specific Rails submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I've found that Rails allows for generic i18n of submit buttons via the following in `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Create %{model}"
      submit: "Save %{model}"
      update: "Update %{model}"
```

However, I'm looking to update the `create` value only for one specific model.  I'd like the text to read as "Upload %{model}" or just "Upload".  How can I make this change for just one model (e.g.: a `Photo` model)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
Those labels can be customized using I18n under the +helpers.submit+ key 
and using %{model} for translation interpolation:

  en:
    helpers:
      submit:
        create: "Create a %{model}"
        update: "Confirm changes to %{model}"

It also searches for a key specific to the given object:

  en:
    helpers:
      submit:
        post:
          create: "Add %{model}"
```

[Source @ actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L2478-L2493)

Answer (score 10):

If you use the [i18n-debug gem](https://github.com/fphilipe/i18n-debug), the rails server will print translations look-up attempts to the console, like:

```
[i18n-debug] en.helpers.submit.post.create => nil
```

Comment: The rails-18n-debug gem this answer links to is nice, but deprecated and the author now recommends to use the alternative gem at https://github.com/fphilipe/i18n-debug