# Placeholder does not replace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use i18n for `View` at Rails4.

## My Rails YAML file and HTML(ERB) file

### YAML

this is the YAML file(for Japanese).

```
---
ja:
  MODEL_NAMEs:
    edit:
      title: 編集：%{model}
```

### HTML

this is html file written by erb.

```
<h2><%= t('.title') %></h2>
```

## Result of View

[image]

## Question

How to replace the placeholder(in this case `%{model}`), automatically model name?

### P.S

@Amit Sharma advice.

```
ja:
  MODEL_NAMEs:
    edit:
      title: "編集：%{model}"
```

and

```
<h2><%= t('MODEL_NAMEs.edit.title', model: "test") %></h2>
```

and `rails` restart. then `編集:test` was shown. 
so. model is may be `nil` or something.

### I want to

```
<h2><%= t('.title') %></h2> #=> 編集：MODEL_NAME
```

Do not rails auto insert model? 
I think auto insert `%{model}`. because `submit` work so.

[I18n for model-specific Rails submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547144/i18n-for-model-specific-rails-submit-button)

Comment: You can try this `"title: 編集：%{model}"` in .yml and in view `<h2><%= t('MODEL_NAMEs.edit.title', model: "test") %></h2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, I hope this will help.

**in YML File.**

```
ja:
  MODEL_NAMEs:
    edit:
      title: "編集：%{model}"
```

**in View File.**

```
<h2><%= t('MODEL_NAMEs.edit.title', model: "test") %></h2>
```

Comment: only `Title` is show in my chrome.

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi you mean to say its not showing `test` right?

Comment: no. `Title`.  `編集` and `test` not show.

Comment: Try this once `<h2><%= t('title', model: 'test') %></h2>`

Comment: also replace this `title: 編集：%{model}` with `title: "編集：%{model}"` in yml file.

Comment: oh, I restart rails. so `編集:test` was shown. I edit my question.

Comment: thank you advice. oh, I forgot write I think how to rails work.