# rails submit_tags to different actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

```
<%= simple_form_for@equipment, :url => equipments_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
    ....
<% if @equipment.id.present? %>
    <div class="actions">
     //TODO submit_tag to action Update
    </div>
<% else %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= submit_tag "Adicionar Equipamento" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

In this example I have two buttons,if the object exists I have the first button and when not exists I have the second button. The second button send a request to controller Equipments#Create. How can I send a request to Equipments#Update in first button ?

Comment: <%= simple_form_for @equipment  do |f| %> This line will automatically handle create or update path by checking whether object is new or not

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= simple_form_for @equipment do |f| %>
  <div class="actions">
     <%= submit_tag(@equipment.persisted? ? "Create Equipment" : "Update Equipment") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the short way to do it.

Usually you would use I18n to translate these labels.
(see: [I18n for model-specific Rails submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547144/i18n-for-model-specific-rails-submit-button))

Comment: I understand your solution but this form receive objects from different models so I need do define da path manually. the path is always the same equipments_path for create and equipment_path to update. how can i do that ?

Comment: @dijiri the equipment_path is automatically added this way.
If you're using one form to submit different models, something has gone terribly wrong.

I think what you mean is: This form is used to create, as well as update an equipment. But with `form_for @equipment` and `resources :equipments` (in your routes) this is automatically generated with the right path and the right method.

Comment: yes, this form is for multiple models. Equipments controller is generic but the models can be tvs, hi-fi, computers etc

Comment: You really should refactor your code to keep it clean and RESTful. (rails conventions)
Please write a controller for every model.